# HTTPS Post Request via PHP and Cookies

Tags: php, post, cookies, https

I am kinda new to PHP however I used JSP a lot before (I have quite information) and everything was easier with Java classes. 
So, now, I want to perform a POST request on a HTTPS page (not HTTP) and need to get returned cookies and past it to another GET request and return the final result. Aim is to make a heavy page for mobile phones more compatible to view in a mobile browser by bypassing the login page and directly taking to the pages which are also served in an ajax user interface.
I am stuck, my code does not work, it says it is Bad Request.

> Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this
>   server could not understand. Reason:
>   You're speaking plain HTTP to an
>   SSL-enabled server port. Instead use
>   the HTTPS scheme to access this URL,
>   please.

```
<?php
$content = '';
$flag = false;
$post_query = 'SOME QUERY'; // name-value pairs
$post_query = urlencode($post_query) . "\r\n";
$host = 'HOST';
$path = 'PATH';
$fp = fsockopen($host, '443');

if ($fp) {
fputs($fp, "POST $path HTTP/1.0\r\n");
fputs($fp, "Host: $host\r\n");
fputs($fp, "Content-length: ". strlen($post_query) ."\r\n\r\n");
fputs($fp, $post_query);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$line = fgets($fp, 10240);
if ($flag) {
$content .= $line;
} else {
$headers .= $line;
if (strlen(trim($line)) == 0) {
$flag = true;
}
}
}
fclose($fp);
}
echo $headers;
echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: what is $host set to?  You need to make sure that that variable has https:\\ in the beginning.  Most likely, it is just plain http:\\

Comment: Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to https://aaaa:443 (Unable to find the socket transport "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?) in C:\xampp\htdocs\1\dene.php on line 8, it says. I got OpenSSL configured and working. Does it mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

From past experience, I've never used PHP's internal functions like `fsocketopen()` for external data posting. The best way to do these actions are using CURL, which gives much more ease and is massively more powerful for developers to leverage.

for example, look at these functions
http://php.net/curl_setopt

and look at the one with URL, POST, POSTDATA, and COOKIESFILES which is for .JAR, which you get then retrieve and that you can use `file_get_contents()` to send the data using GET.

Comment: I am confused, it is set_opt means set option, how can I get the cookies returned? I looked a few examples and can't figure out.